# How do I rewrite from a specific dynamic page to the non-existent directory of my choice?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to use my htaccess file to redirect a variety of specific known dynamic URLS to various "non-existent" directories of my choice according to the subject matter that the originally dynamically produced file contains.  Below is my latest attempt (which still does not work).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=([8][3])$

RewriteRule ^comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly\.html$ /show_rss_item.php?%1
```

WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO:

I have two goals:

1) When someone keys in "show_rss_item.php?ID=83" they should see their URL bar read-out: 
comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly.html

2) When someone keys in 
comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly.html

they should see the content that is created "behind-the-scenes", so to speak, by show_rss_item.php?ID=83

I find lots of information online about using variables in rewrite rules, but please note that that is not what I am doing here, although the original content is produced dynamically.  In my case, I am merely trying to hard-code a sort of "one-off" rewrite rule for each article in my database, so that I can assign an appropriate virtual human readable directory location in my htaccess file rather than having the site visitor see the dynamic URL in their browser address bar.

These dynamic URLs, in my case, always take the form of:
show_rss_item.php?ID=article_number_here.

I have been trying to do this for weeks. In fact, I just lost $50 to a Guru "professional" who, after over an hour of chat, turned out to know less about the subject than I did and finally ended up suggesting that I try JavaScript.

Comment: Here's my latest try which doesn't work:

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=([8][3])$
RewriteRule ^comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly\.html$ /show_rss_item.php?$1 and also tried.... comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly\.html$ /show_rss_item.php?ID=83

Answer (score 1):

You have two rules here, redirect `show_rss_item.php?ID=83` to `.../just-plane-silly.html`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=83$
RewriteRule ^/?show_rss_item.php$ /comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly.html [R,L]
```

and show the real content, if you receive a request for `.../just-plane-silly.html`

```
RewriteRule ^/?comedy-routines/television/just-plane-silly\.html$ /show_rss_item.php?ID=83 [L]
```